# pressing enter calls the code in click method

Tags: angular, click, keyup

I have two input fields and button.
when I press Enter in one of the two input fields supposed to execute some code but what happens the code of button is executed

```
<div class="input-group">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
     (click)="getCurrency()"
          style="margin-right: 10px;width: 20px">...</button>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <input id="currencyDesc"  type="text" size="15" [(ngModel)]='name' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <input formControlName="CRCYIsn" type="text" size="4" (keyup.enter)="currencyByIsn()">
        </div>

        <label> : العملة</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: getCurrency method is called in addition to currencyByIsn? or just getCurrency is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  `(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"` as below on that button:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
       type="button"
       (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" 
       (click)="getCurrency()"
        style="margin-right: 10px;width: 20px">...</button>
```

If it's a form, try to put this code on the `<form>` tag itself

Comment: @NouraAli Which button are we talking about ? The same one which calls `getCurrency()` ?

Comment: Thank you, I put (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"  in the form tag and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

For ENTER key, why not use **(keyup.enter)**

```
  <div class="input-group">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
         (click)="getCurrency()"
              style="margin-right: 10px;width: 20px">...</button>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <input id="currencyDesc" (keyup.enter)="doSomething()" type="text" size="15" [(ngModel)]='name' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <input formControlName="CRCYIsn" (keyup.enter)="doSomething()" type="text" size="4" (keyup.enter)="currencyByIsn()">
            </div>

            <label> : العملة</label>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will change the next things:

- First, you should use only formcontrolname if that div inside a form. It´s better than use ngForm.
- Second, I think it´s better use (click) instead of (keyup.enter), or directly use (ng-submit) if this method is executed when the form is submitted.
- Finally, don't mix html code with css, use css files for that component that is one of Angular's best qualities

Answer (score 0):

Buttons inside forms are by default of type `submit`. Tell the button to be of type `button` and it shouldn't be fired:

```html
<button mat-raised-button type="button" color="primary" (click)="getCurrency()">
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-dvn46r?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

**Also like mentioned, don't mix reactive forms with `ngModel`.**